# amp-lightbox opened on another amp-lightbox closes both

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to open a amp-lightbox on click on another amp-lightbox. but it results in closing both of them. can anyone suggest me a way to open them one on top of the other and close them in a similar manner?

```
  <div>
    <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay">
      <div class="lightbox" on="tap:my-lightbox-1" role="button" tabindex="0">
        <h1>First Light box</h1>
      </div>
    </amp-lightbox>
    <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox-1" layout="nodisplay"role="button" tabindex="1">
      <div class="lightbox">
        <h1>Second Light box</h1>
      </div>
    </amp-lightbox>
    <button on="tap:my-lightbox">
      Open lightbox
    </button>
  </div>
```

Is it happening because the first lightbox is losing the focus and thus it closes it and since the parent closes and re-renders the child amp-lightbox ?
also, is it possible to do it with css instead of using amp-lightbox

Comment: is this valid? did you check using https://validator.ampproject.org/#

Comment: yes it is valid @JayGray

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
<div>
    
    <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox" layout="nodisplay">
      <div class="lightbox">
        <button on="tap:my-lightbox.close,my-lightbox-1.open">
            Open Second lightbox
          </button> 
          <button on="tap:my-lightbox.close">
            Close first lightbox
          </button>
        <h1>First Light box</h1>
      </div>
    </amp-lightbox>

    <amp-lightbox id="my-lightbox-1" layout="nodisplay">
      <div class="lightbox">
        <button on="tap:my-lightbox-1.close,my-lightbox.open">
            Close Second lightbox
          </button>   
        <h1>Second Light box</h1>
      </div>
    </amp-lightbox>


    <button on="tap:my-lightbox.open">
      Open first lightbox
    </button>
  </div>
```

Working example **[CLICK HERE](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/rNxqxoz)**

Comment: very nice example

Comment: but if there is some state is set in first amp it will be lost right?

Comment: Not sure can you share example link with me